# If the image of two matrices always have the same norm, are they essentially equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Define the matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and suppose they satisfy

$ \| A x \|_p = \| B x \|_p, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n. $

Does this imply that $A = Q B$, where $Q$ is an isometry with respect to the $\ell_p$-norm?

Comment: Should be true when $n=2$ by SVD.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is there an "$\ell_{p}$-SVD"?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this question for $p \in (0,2)$ in the following publication: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/pad17a/pad17a.pdf